# How to center an icon to a trailing Container within a list tile?

Tags: flutter

i am trying to center a delete icon to a trailing container that's within a list tile

i tried using the alignment option for the icon button but it didn't work, i also tried to use the center widget for the icon Button too, also didn't work, what did i do wrong?

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: ListTile(
        onTap: () {},
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        ),
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 20),
        tileColor: Colors.white,
        leading: Icon(Icons.check_box, color: tdBlue),
        title: Text(
          'Check Mail',
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 16,
              color: tdblack,
              decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough),
        ),
        trailing: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12),
          width: 25,
          height: 25,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: tdRed,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
          ),
          child: IconButton(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            color: Colors.white,
            iconSize: 18,
            icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[that's how my code and app look like at the moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLA4R.png)

Answer (score 0):

Because container is the parent widget and icon is child so You need to use `alignment: Alignment.center,` for container as well

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: ListTile(
        onTap: () {},
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        ),
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 20),
        tileColor: Colors.white,
        leading: Icon(Icons.check_box, color: tdBlue),
        title: Text(
          'Check Mail',
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 16,
              color: tdblack,
              decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough),
        ),
        trailing: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12),
          width: 25,
          height: 25,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: tdRed,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
          ),
          child: IconButton(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            color: Colors.white,
            iconSize: 18,
            icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The IconButton class has a padding parameter which defaults to 8.0 if not explicitly defined. This padding affects the Icon widget of the IconButton class, hence the reason why it looks shifted. [IconButton's padding property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/IconButton/padding.html#:%7E:text=The%20padding%20around%20the%20button%27s,8.0%20padding%20on%20all%20sides.)

> The padding around the button's icon. The entire padded icon will react to input gestures.
> This property can be null. If null, it defaults to 8.0 padding on all sides.

To resolve the issue, you can set **padding to 0.0** in the IconButton class.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: ListTile(
        onTap: () {},
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        ),
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 20),
        tileColor: Colors.white,
        leading: Icon(Icons.check_box, color: tdBlue),
        title: Text(
          'Check Mail',
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 16,
              color: tdblack,
              decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough),
        ),
        trailing: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12),
          width: 25,
          height: 25,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: tdRed,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
          ),
          child: IconButton(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
            color: Colors.white,
            iconSize: 18,
            icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use `Ink` and `Icon`.

```
Ink(
  width: 25,
  height: 25,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.red,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
  ),
  child: const Icon(
    size: 18,
    Icons.delete,
    color: Colors.white,
  ),
),
```